# Integrar Facebook en una App con WebView

Tags: android, webview-android

Cómo puedo integrar una página de Facebook en mi aplicación con `WebView`, lo hice de forma básica pero solo me muestra la cabecera de la página, cuando empiezo a realizar scroll hacia abajo se queda ahí en la cabecera.

Este es mi código:

```
  WebView myWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    //myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.adventistas.org/es/");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/adventistasrosarioeste/?ref=br_tf");
```

¿Como podría hacer que mi página que se encuentra en el `WebView` pueda realizar scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es correcto lo que tratas de realizar pero en este caso la clase `Callback` es simplemente un `WebViewClient` donde debes sobre escribir el método `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` :

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);

myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
     @Override
      public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
          return false;
       }
    });

myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/adventistasrosarioeste/?ref=br_tf");
```

Para asegurar se cargue la página y puedas ver su contenido, es necesario definir la propiedad  `android:layout_height="match_parent"`  :

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

este sería el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obviamente necesitas el permiso:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys anda perfectamente bien